# How does Quill determine where to place the cursor based on mouse position?

Tags: quill

After combining Quill and Interact.js, it seems like the events are being overlapped. Whenever I click on the Quill editor, it doesn't know where to place the cursor. I have tried firing the 'focus' event on the Quill editor but it just uses the last range and does not place the cursor where the mouse is hovering the text.

I'd like to fire the same event/call the same function that Quill does when detecting the mouse click on text.